# Js filter out items according to nested object

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have a result array, which I want to modify.
I want to remove from each item the fields of `excluded languages`.

Eventually I want to filter out any result whith an empty languages array (after modification).

I have tried this code, but after the first modification I get `filteredPairs == undefined`.

Originally `filteredPairs != undefined`.

```
filteredPairs = filteredPairs.forEach(item => item.result.name
  .map(langPair => {
    if (!negLanguagesParam.includes(langPair["@language"])) {
      return langPair;
    }
    return null;
  }));
filteredPairs = filteredPairs.filter(item => item.result.name.length == 0);
```

Data sample:

[image]

Comment: Could you provide the input data? A [mcve]?

Comment: `forEach` returns undefined, and you're assigning that to `filteredPairs` in the first line

Comment: @pilchard how can rewrite it ?

Comment: You'll need top provide sample data, but a good start would be to use `map()` rather than `forEach()`.

Comment: @pilchard add. Tried "map" before, but I didn't know how to iterate the "name" array, whilst returning the upper level item.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is an example using a `.filter()` call inside a `.map()` to initially filter the nested `result.name` arrays. The returned array is then filtered using a final `.filter()` call to check for empty arrays.

```js
const negLanguagesParam = ['it'];

const filteredInput = input
  .map(({ item, result }) => ({
    ...item,
    result: {
      ...result,
      name: result.name
        .filter(({ '@language': lang }) => !negLanguagesParam.includes(lang))
    }
  }))
  .filter(({ result: { name } }) => name.length);

console.log(JSON.stringify(filteredInput, null, 2));
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

```html
<script>
const input = [
  {
    result: {
      name: [
        { '@language': 'en' },
        { '@language': 'it' }
      ]
    }
  },
  {
    result: {
      name: [
        { '@language': 'it' }
      ]
    }
  }
];
</script>
```

Comment: Can you please explain this syntax? `.map(({ item, result }) => ({
    ...item,` map of a newly constructed object? and also `...item` what does the dots syntax mean?

Comment: The `...item` is [spread syntax](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax) which expands, or copies the properties of the `item` object into a new object. The declaration of `({item, result}) => ..` is [destructuring assignment](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment) which is allows us to access and assign the values of properties to a variable at the same time.